# Summing scope integer value & a pure number in angularjs template part

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I in controller scrope I have object property with integer value (example. 300), lets say it's under config object - `$scope.config.headers.width = 300;`

I'm trying to do sum in template as this:

```
<div id="First-Window" style="left: {{config.headers.width+30}}px;">
```

But it does not recognize config.headers.width as integer and returns string value, in this case 30030px. Can I fix this in template level? I know that I can use function and just add the value before adding it to template, but I think logically it should be possible to sum such things under template level somehow, or not?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I have done it by defining $scope.parseInt function as:

$scope.parseInt = function (n) {
    return parseInt(n);
};

And template part:

```
<div id="First-Window" style="left: {{ parseInt(config.headers.width) + 30 }}px;">
```

Please let me know if there is even better solution for this.